# remove text between ',' and 'space ,' if found using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, string

I have text like this

```
Vindu1: Antall: 4, Bredde i mm:  , Hoyde i mm: 1.
```

If there is an empty space followed by '`,`' (`' ,'`) I want to remove all the text before it until find `','`

the result will looks like

```
Vindu1: Antall 4, Hoyde i mm: 1.
```

I know I should use preg_replace function to do it but I can't figuere out what is the regular expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
preg_replace('/(?<=,|^)[^,]+ ,/', '', $str);
```

Example:

```
$str = "Vindu1: Antall: 4, Bredde i mm: , Hoyde i mm: 1.";
echo preg_replace('/(?<=,|^)[^,]+ ,/', '', $str);
```

Output:

```
Vindu1: Antall: 4, Hoyde i mm: 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace('/\\s+,/', ',')` should do it

Comment: Won't that just remove whitespace before the comma?

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = 'Vindu1: Antall: 4, Bredde i mm: , Hoyde i mm: 1.'

if(strstr($text, ' ,'))
{

    $text=explode(' ,', $text);
    $text1 = $text[0];
    $text2 = $text[1];

    $text = explode(',', $text1);

    $result = $text[0].','.$text2;

}
```

Apologies for the variable naming, can't think of anything sensible at the moment.